# remove both commas and white space ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string, palindrome

I am new to ruby and my regex knowledge leaves a lot to be desired. I am trying to check if a string is a palindrome, but wish to ignore white space and commas.

The current code I have is

```
def palindrome(string)
  string = string.downcase
  string = string.gsub(/\d+(,)\d+//\s/ ,"")
  if string.reverse == string
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want `"pat, tap"` to return `true`? Note that the body of your can be written as a single line: `string.downcase.gsub(/\d+(,)\d+//\s/ ,"") == string`. You don't need `return` as the last calculated value is returned.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> but wish to ignore white space and commas

You don't need to put `\d` in your regex. Just replace the spaces or commas with empty string.

```
string = string.gsub(/[\s,]/ ,"")
```

The above gsub command would remove all the spaces or commas. `[\s,]` character class which matches a space or comma.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use the method [String#tr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr):

```
str = "pat, \t \ntap"

str.tr(" ,\t\n", '') #=> "pattap"
```